# Paging, sorting and filtering in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

Can somebody please explain me about custom paging, filtering and sorting . Though I have searched on Internet about these things but all those ways are difficult to understand. do any body have a better approach to do paging, filtering and sorting in  a single query. also How I will be able to do all those things in a single query Actually I have created a grid using forloop. So , how can I do paging and filtering custom.I have checked the loginc but i hav not understood . Row number is being used in many of the examples of paging online. can somebody please explain this. Sorry for the poor english. Please help me ASAP. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find grids the easiest way to display large amounts of data. You could try googling examples of the [asp:GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx). The basic functionalities a grid automatically adds for you (when you enable paging) are:

- Previous page, next page and similar buttons to move between pages
- Max page/item count
- Current page

An important not on paging:

- Client side paging: load *all* the data at once, but only display 10/15/20/... items at once
- Server side paging: only load the page you are viewing (so every time you go to a different page there is a database call needed)

Generally, client side paging is the 'default'. Give a list to your grid, set the number of items you want to see per page and you're done. This works well enough for small tables (a few dozen items), but if scales very poorly. If you have a million items in your table, it will try (and most likely fail) to load all of them before displaying anything.

You can put a hard limit on how many items you show, but the best way to handle large tables is server side paging. For this, some customization will be needed though. Here is where the 'rownumber' you mentioned is needed ([Server Side paging example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125541/Effective-Paging-with-GridView-Control-in-ASP-NET)). Having a rownumber lets you fetch a 'page'. Example:

- Page: 5
- Total (Number of records): 100
- PageSize (Number of records shown per page): 10

If you would want the records for page 5, you would need to sort your list somehow and then take the records 41 to 50 to show the content of page 5. In a query, this could be done with a `ROWNUMBER BETWEEN ((Page - 1) * PageSize) + 1 AND Page * PageSize`. In Entity Framework you can use `.Skip((Page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize)` do get the same result.

Note: paging is assumed to start at 1 (first page = page 1) in the above example.